# Settings up Paging Control

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I am trying to set up Page Control and I was using Apple's example of Page Control as a springboard to integrate into my app.

My main question is that in the Apple example it is using the initWithXib and I don't use that anymore. I drew it on storyboard and linked it to the class that I am pointing to when it's loading a scrollViewPage. It however does not show up? Is there a initWithStoryboard like the Xib?

After researching, I tried initWithCoder, but it didn't work or I coded it wrong.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!
Alan

Comment: You'll want to use [initWithCoder](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8373223/420001) and awakeFromNib.

Comment: Do I need to use both or just initWithCoder? How do I fill in initWithCoder to load the view i built? THanks!