# Custom UIView is initialized using init(coder), how do I initialize it using init(frame)

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

So I overrode the `init(frame)` to do a bunch of stuff:

```
class InputField: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame);
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 8, y: 8, width: 73, height: 30));
        label.text = "I want";
        label.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Book", size: 26.0);
        addSubview(label);
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .leadingMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 8.0).isActive = true;

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder);
    }

}
```

The problem is that the second `init()` is called not the first one. The way I have it set up in storyboard is by having a plain empty `UIView` whose class is `InputField`. Why does it use the second one and not the first one?

I don't want to create the InputField programmatically as I'd much rather see the Views I'm setting up in the storyboard. I know how to if I'm stuck, but I mostly wanna learn how to do it this way.

**edit:** as stated in comment, the current workaround is doing that configuration code in `init(coder)`. But this still doesn't answer: Why is that being called and not `init(frame)`?

Comment: Any configuration code, such as what you have in your init frame override, may be placed in a separate method and called from any or all initializers.

Comment: Yeah I realized that. I set it up so that the code is called in init(decoder). But then why does init(frame) exist though?

Comment: here's a thorough answer for that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373176/how-is-view-initialized-when-loaded-via-a-storyboard

Comment: That's exactly what i needed, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different *convenience methods* to help initialize a view. When a view is actually initialized *only one* of the many methods(*-frame, -coder, etc*) are going to be invoked.
If you need to perform any custom initialization, you can have a [`common init`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7226239/objective-c-custom-view-and-implementing-init-method) method.

Comment: Yeahh I'll do that. Thanks!