# What is the best way to initialize an object?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've been using Objective-C for a few years, but I'm still unsure how to initialize an object. Our problem is this:

```
-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        self.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }
    return self;
}

-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Getting it to be initialized the same in both methods means either copy and paste coding (huge no-no, causes endless problems due to human error, such as values being different, like in the example above) or a new method:

```
-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self initialSetup];
    }
    return self;
}

-(id)initialSetup {
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    self.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
}
```

This then has the problem that if a subclass has an `initialSetup` method, the superclass calling `[self initialSetup]` will call the subclass's `initialSetup`, and thus ignore all of the superclass's setup. You can get around this by appending the class name each time, such as `initialSetupTextField`.

This seems rather messy though. This is all just to initialize an object. How does everyone else do this?

Comment: why not call [super initialSetup] in the subclass's initialSetup?

Comment: I think you need to look into the concept of the Designated Initializer.

Comment: closely related, maybe even a dupe: [Objective C - Custom view and implementing init method?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7226239/643383)

Answer (score 9):

Every class should have a *designated initializer*;  the one true `init...` method variant that must always be called to properly initialize the class (as Matt states).

However, that doesn't fully solve the problem in that a class may also support instantiation through unarchival, which runs into the same "where do I put the common initialization goop" problem in your question.

Typically, I create a method like:

```
- (void)commonInit
{
     ... common initialization goop goes here ...
}
```

And then call it *first* from the designated initializers and/or `initWithCoder:`.

Yes, a bit messy, but not much you can do about it.

A general strategy to reduce the mess:

• provide very very few initializers;  maybe `init` + one initializer with all the possible arguments for other configurations.

• Designate the `super`'s initializer as your DI and make any additional initializers call through it.   When subclassing where you have a more specific DI (see `UIView`'s `initWithFrame:`), override the super's DI to call `[self initFancy:...]` which then calls `[super initThroughSupersDI]`.

Answer (score 8):

You're missing the concept of a [Designated Initializer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/MultipleInitializers.html). You write one init method that does the heavy lifting. All other initializers just call the designated initializer. Your example would look like:

```
-(id)init {
    return [self initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
}

-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Well stated in regards to the concept of "Designated Initializers", but doesn't cover the `initWithCoder:` case.

Comment: That's true, thanks for pointing it out. I'll defer to your answer on that point, since I would end up saying the exact same thing.

Comment: And since I refer to your answer... infinite loop! :)

Answer (score 1):

> …appending the class name each time, such as `-initialSetupTextField`

Yes, exactly that, or you can create a C function for your private instance initialization routine -- when the designated initializer is insufficient. I use a different naming scheme from yours, but as long as you use a convention which avoids collision, then you're good. I'm mentioning that because the method in your example could be confused for a getter.

Another thing I do is return a value from this routine which indicates whether there was an error (i.e. `nil` should be returned).